# Prevent Visual Studio Code auto-completing incorrectly whilst I type

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm having an issue with VS Code autocomplete (intellisense?) that seems completely illogical, but I can't figure out how to disable it (partly because I've no idea what to actually search for this.)

My most recent example is illustrated in the screenshot below. I am typing out a media query `@media (min-width: 768px)`

I then follow this up with `and` to continue the query, yet VS Code has for some reason decided I must want to insert a random unrelated variable here. It doesn't even have the string `and` anywhere in the variable names suggested.

I am fine with suggestions - they are useful when I want. But the second I hit the space bar, it automatically replaces my text. It is replacing my text despite me doing nothing other than typing what I want to type.

So many times I have been caught out because my correctly typed code is being replaced without any interaction whatsoever on my part. How do I prevent this happening?

Thanks for any help.

[image: Image showing the autocomplete issue described]

Comment: you can set the suggestion to only happen on Enter or Tab or Enter/Tab, it is never on Space

Comment: the suggestions contain the characters `a` and `n` and `d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense does not autocomplete on space, and this is not part of its [default config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_settings) either. Therefore this is either a bug ([which could be the case](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3647)), or a misconfiguration caused by an extension or changes to settings.json.

One solution for it would be to disable autocomplete on commit character altogether with `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false` in settings.json. If `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"` is left untouched, autocomplete will then only be triggered on tab/enter.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it turned out it was an extension I was using. Unfortunately the plugin had no options to prevent this, but your solution seems to have solved the issue for me!